# Distance calculation in MongoDB using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: mongodb, location, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:-

```
{
    location : {
        lat : <Latitude>,
        lng : <Longitude>
    },
    timestamp : "Unix timestamp"
}
```

I want to calculate distance in KM between all location point sorted by timestamps in ascending order. I am new to mongoDb. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could edit your question to include the attempts you have made with the `aggregation` thus far.

Comment: @chridam:- I went through the concept of aggregation and Grouping but unable to get solution....

Answer (score 0):

I know am a bit late but this worked for me.

First, you need to update your collection schema or model

```
location: {
    type: {type: String, default:'Point'},
    coordinates: {type: [Number], default: [0,0], index: '2dsphere'}
}
```

```
**Mongodb Query**

collectionName.aggregate([{
        $geoNear: {
            near: {type: "Point", coordinates: ['76.768066', '30.741482']}, // Your center point longitude and latitude
            distanceField: "distance", // Field name
            maxDistance: 5000,  // Max distance radius in metres
            spherical: true, // Calculates distances using spherical geometry
            key: "location", // Collection key
            distanceMultiplier : 0.001, // KM
        }
    },
    { $sort : { createdAt : -1 } } // Sort createdAt in ascending order
])
```